# How to sort an object std::vector by its float value

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a C++ std::vector denoted as:

```
std::vector<GameObject*> vectorToSort;
```

Each object in vectorToSort contains a float parameter which is returned by calling "DistanceFromCamera()":

```
vectorToSort.at(position)->DistanceFromCamera();
```

I wish to sort the vector by this float parameter however std::sort does not appear to be able to do this. How can I achieve this sort?

Comment: I guess you mean that GameObject has a method called DistanceFromCamera() and not std::vector<GameObject*>

Comment: Magnus, definitely, I corrected that for him :-P

Comment: Yes you are correct, I just updated the code with what I am currently using. Thank you for the speedy answer Evan, I'm testing it now. I'll get back to you asap

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you want to use a predicate like this:

```
struct VectorSortP {
    bool operator()(const GameObject *a, const GameObject *b) const {
        return a->DistanceFromCamera() < b->DistanceFromCamera();
    }
};

std::sort(vectorToSort.begin(), vectorToSort.end(), VectorSortP());
```

Comment: I am getting an error: C2804: binary 'operator <' has too many parameters (referring to the line starting with: "bool operator<(const").

Comment: It's got to be an operator() instead of an operator<

Comment: Aaah, it should be operator(). It's a functor.

Comment: I tried to figure it out, but you guys beat me to it :) Thanks it works!

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: thanks for the edit, i was a bit too eager to get the answer out fast ;).